# std::search with an empty subsequence

Tags: c++, std

What should `std::search` return if 3rd and 4th arguments are equal?

```
std::string s = "1", ss;
std::search(s.begin(), s.end(), ss.begin(), ss.end()) == ?
```

More precisely -- what does the standard say about it?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.search https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search

Comment: *"Returns first1 if [first2, last2) is empty"* From the link above.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, oh right... because they named it there `s_first`/`s_last`, I thought it was talking about `first`/`last`, because I'm used to `first2`/`last2`